# Network Error, Windows cannot access \\PC080

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, windows-8.1

I'm not able to open the shared folders of my friend's computer even though i'm able to ping with ip

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2bnZ.png)

My sytem os is Windows 10 and my friend's os is Windows 8.1. Other's are using Windows 10 are still able to connect with my friend. I do not know what crp has gone wrong with my system.

Other users in the network are able to connect to my friend's shared folder and everything but not me. I have posted the error in the screenshot. Someone could please help on that.